# Protocol to identify individuals by SSL certificate and personal DNS address

Tags: authentication, ssl, dns, identity

Are you familiar with a protocol that allows private individuals to identify themselves by their own DNS address and SSL certificate?
I'm familiar with client side certificates but I'm talking about something that would be simpler to use than carrying around a private key.

For example, in order to authenticate myself and login to a website I will just provide my "ID" site: https://my-first-name.last-name.my-private-domain.com where a server would be available with a valid SSL certificate for my specific subdomain. The DNS address can also include a whois record and phone/email address etc. Or any data in the TXT record for that matter.

The site could then identify me in several ways, it can email me, text me or simply encrypt my data with my own public key.

Did someone do this anywhere? Research it?

Comment: I think this question should better be asked at security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thanks. I reposted it there.